# Change PostgreSQL date language from request

Tags: postgresql, locale, postgresql-9.4

I'm kind of new to PostgreSQL and I'm trying to change the locale of the date function results, to get the result of `to_char(my_date, 'Month')` in another language.

Here are some of my settings :

```
$> show lc_time;

en_US.UTF-8
```

I found in the documentation that the locale could be changed at the database initialization :

```
initdb --locale=fr_FR
```

But that's not exactly what I'm looking for.

In MySQL, I used to do it like :

```
SET lc_time_names = 'fr_FR';
```

But unfortunately, I can't find a way to do it with PostgreSQL. Is there any ?

Comment: Try this :  `select set_config('lc_time', 'fr_FR', true);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the localized version of the name of the month with the special `TM` format (translation mode):

```
to_char(my_date, 'TMMonth')
```

You can also apply this to the names of the weekdays with `TMD`. Both versions will display the names using the locale of the server, unless the `lc_time` run-time parameter has a specific setting. That setting can also be changed for the current session:

```
SET lc_time = 'fr_FR';
```

When you want to revert back to the default setting in the same session, use:

```
SET lc_time TO DEFAULT;
```

Comment: Yes but my database is initialized in English, and my purpose is to get the month name in another language.

Comment: Thanks, the last edit seems to be what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can set function-scoped config parameters (including in [`IMMUTABLE` or `STABLE` functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/xfunc-volatility.html)) with [`set_config(setting_name, new_value, is_local)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-admin.html).

So, if you want to format your date in `fr_FR` you can do something like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION format_month() RETURNS TEXT AS $$
  SELECT set_config('lc_time', 'fr_FR.utf8', true);
  SELECT to_char(now(), 'TMMonth');
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

(Note the [`TM-` prefix](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-formatting.html) enables translation mode, which prints localized day and month names based on `lc_time`.)

On my computer, the above function produced an error until I installed the `fr_FR` locale and restarted postgres. How you do that depends on your OS, but on Ubuntu I used [`dpkg-reconfigure locales`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue).