# how to change the timestamp format in other language PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, diff, subtraction

PostgreSQL timestamp:

```
begin= '2018-06-07 08:29:49'
end  = '2018-06-10 04:07:57'
```

QUERY:

```
select sa.\"end\"::timestamp(0) - sa.begin::timestamp(0)
from tabelle sa;
```

Output:

> 2 days 19:38:08

I would like to change this output "days" into "Tage", like:

> 2 Tage 19:38:08

Most important, when there is month different then it should display months in 'Monate', the same goes for years to 'Jahre'.

i tried to look about dateformat, but i need to change expr format not format like '%Y %m %d ...etc.

i tried this too:

```
to_char(extract(year from (sa."end"::timestamp - sa.begin::timestamp)),'00')||' Jahre '||to_char(extract(month from (sa."end"::timestamp - sa.begin::timestamp)),'00')||' Monate '||to_char(extract(day from (sa."end"::timestamp - sa.begin::timestamp)),'00')||' Tage '||to_char(extract(hour from (sa."end"::timestamp - sa.begin::timestamp)),'00')||':'||to_char(extract(minute from (sa."end"::timestamp - sa.begin::timestamp)),'00')||':'||to_char(extract(second from (sa."end"::timestamp - sa.begin::timestamp)),'00')
```

Output:

> 00 Jahre  00 Monate  02 Tage  19: 38: 08

it doesn't look good, cause month or year shall appear if there is number.

Important, only this 'day' needed to be changed in 'Tage' not setting character UFT8 or other things complete in german language!!!

Please i need your support.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change PostgreSQL date language from request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009076/change-postgresql-date-language-from-request)

Comment: Hello Georgie, no this is not same, i don't wish to set ufc in germany language never! but only this type 'days' may be changed!

Comment: It IS a duplicate. You can do something like: `SET lc_time = 'de_DE' ; SELECT YOUR THINGS; SET lc_time TO DEFAULT`

Answer (score 0):

There is some solution but in other way:

```
select extract(day from (sa.\"end\"::timestamp - sa.begin::timestamp))||' Tage '||
       to_char(extract(hour from (sa.\"end\"::timestamp-sa.begin::timestamp)),'00')||':'||
       to_char(extract(minute from (sa.\"end\"::timestamp - sa.begin::timestamp)),'00')||':'||
       to_char(extract(second from (sa.\"end\"::timestamp - sa.begin::timestamp)),'00')
       from tabelle sa
```

Output:

> 2 Tage 19: 38: 08